# Implementations of JavaScript stream ciphers?

Tags: javascript, encryption

Are there any free to use implementations of stream ciphers available for JavaScript?

Especially interested in HC-128, Salsa20/12 or SOSEMANUK as these are recommended by [The eSTREAM Project](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Section D of [Symmetric Cryptography in Javascript](http://crypto.stanford.edu/sjcl/acsac.pdf) refers to a "Javascript implementation of Salsa20/12" but I can't find the implementation on their [github repo](https://github.com/bitwiseshiftleft/sjcl).

> We compared Javascript AES with a Javascript implementation of
>   Salsa20/12 [20], one of the fastest eSTREAM ciphers. A native x86
>   implementation of Salsa20/12 is about 5 times faster than a native
>   implementation of 128-bit AES. Surprisingly, Table VII shows that when
>   both algorithms are implemented in Javascript, Salsa 20/12 is
>   comparable in speed to AES. We believe that this discrepancy is
>   primarily due to Javascript’s lack of 128-bit SIMD instructions or of
>   64-bit registers, and secondarily due to Salsa20/12’s larger state
>   spilling to memory.

Answer (score 1):

This is the version **Kevin Hakanson** was referring to: https://gist.github.com/dchest/4126510 . It has a pretty decent I/O throughput (110MB/s), and seems to follow the spec to the letter. I have not, however, tested it, as I have no reference to test it against besides looking at the ops and compare them to the RFC...so use at your own risk!

Comment: (For SOSEMANUK, I doubt you'll find an implementation in pure JS, as one part of the cipher is a round of Serpent - and I'm not sure if anyone has written this. I'll write it if I have some spare time)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about any JavaScript implementations of those, but if you have a serverside implementation, you can think about sending it to your server via an ajax request (over https) and getting the result as the response.  :)

Comment: This would be significantly slower than running it in JS. Not just this, but it also exposes you to potential MITM attacks in specific cases.